# Login screen items misplaced

Tags: greeter, pantheon

I installed elementaryOS 2 days ago and everything works fine. 
The only issue I was not able to resolve:

The time displayed on the login screen is cut off and the items seem to be misplaced alltogether (see picture).

I am using elementary on my desktop PC with a screen resolution of 1920x1080.

Is there a way to readjust this?

---

EDIT:

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

[image: elements are off center]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **Settings** > **Display** > Set scaling factor to **Automatic** and click on the gear icon upper left corner from the blue area and select screen solution to **1366 * 768**.

Don't forget to vote down this answer if it doesn't help. Pleas read [VOTE - The site needs it](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/vote-the-site-needs-it).

Comment: I choose the closest option available to your suggested resolution, still the same problem. In fact, the login screen seems to be unaffected by the change of resolution.

Comment: I see can you please edit the question with the output of `xrandr -q`

Comment: Can please execute this command in terminal `xrandr --output <OUTPUT> --mode 1600x1200` ? After that please sign out and sign in again and let me know what happens.

Comment: This changes the screen resolution to 1600x1200 as expected. However, it doesn't affect the login screen.
(Sorry for the late answer)

Comment: For me there is only "LoDPI" and "Double Pixel" available. No automatic. Where is the automatic option?